# How do I access a php array value containing a forward slash

Tags: php, arrays

I've been around these yer' internets many a time and I seem to be able to find an answer. I have also tried every combination I can think of.

I have an array

```
["results"]=> array(20) {
[0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (6) 
["area"]=> string(9) "Flint, MI"
["tag/_text"]=> string(11) "sevenseas"
....
```

I'm trying to access the "tag/_text" within a loop can't seem to

```
foreach ($holder as $dets) {
    $tag  = $dets->tag/_text; 
    $area  = $dets->area;
 }
```

How do I get the $tag value?

Comment: access it like an array `$dets["tag/_text"]`

Comment: or `$dets->{"tag/_text"}`

Comment: The output is not very useful. Please post the result of `var_export($yourVariable);` instead.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in ....
I get the following error when I do $dets["tag/_text"]

Comment: can you provide us with the actual results of `var_dump($holder)` ?

Comment: @Leggendario $dets->{"tag/_text"} works, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex
It explains that you can use curly brackets to create complex expressions.

You can access the property of the object with the following expression `$dets->{'tag/_text'}`